# Passing a pointer as a ROS msg

Tags: ros, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, im creating a basic vision system which implements filters through a pipeline structure. My point cloud is grabbed by a kinect. The thing is i would like t send just a pointer to the cloud as a ROS message, in order to get a faster and more efficient processing. Is there a way to do this? thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31470/passing-a-pointer-as-a-ros-msg/) by [Alekzander](https://answers.ros.org/users/2145/alekzander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

...not as such. ROS messages are transmitted over the network; as a result, "passing a pointer" doesn't make any sense.

But wait, there's more!

One possibility is to just implement your pipeline in a single node; then it can pass pointers around because it's all in one process.

Another is to use [nodelets](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet), which offer a way of defining something that behaves like a node, but lets you have several in the same process; these were devised to solve exactly the problem you're talking about.

A third option is [ecto](http://plasmodic.org/); where ROS is by-design asynchronous (which makes multi-input perceptual pipelines very painful), ecto is by-design synchronous, to make such pipelines easy. Ecto's still in heavy development, but it'll be seriously cool when it's done.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9